# Working with folders having an extension on iOS

Tags: ios, file, directory

I'm working on an application that downloads folders from the internet.
A folder contains several files, and has an extension to be downloaded in an easier way.
I would like to store the folder locally, and then access the contents of said folder.

For example, folder.ext contains data.txt, picture.jpg and database.db.
How can I tell iOS to use folder.ext as a folder and not a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension is irrelevant. You treat the folder like any other folder. `NSFileManager` has several methods for creating folders and getting their contents. The fact that your folder name has an extension has no effect at all.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the way I create the folder by importing it as a zip first, and then use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES  attributes:nil error:nil]` to create the folder.